# Can ExpressMapper take Interfaces in the Register function?

Tags: c#

I have interfaces of the objects, the internal objects are not exposed.
Can I use something like this:

```
Mapper.Register<IProduct,IProductViewModel>();
```

When I try to do this, I get an exception which says "Cannot instantiate Interfaces".

Comment: you have to give concrete class for ``IProduct`` because container needs to instantiate object and interfaces cannot be instantiated in c#

Comment: Do I need to give objects or just the type?

Comment: you need type name like ProductViewModel

Comment: Thanks @EhsanSajjad!! Lemme try this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently ExpressMapper doesn't support registration and mapping handling of inherited and interface types officially but version 2.0 is going to support that! There is a [feature in a github](https://github.com/expressmapper/ExpressMapper/issues/2).

Answer (score 1):

It can only register an interface as the **source** Type. In this case, only members declared in the interface would be mapped. Mind that properties with the same name (in both source and target types) are auto mapped too, unless you explicitly ignore them. In short - you can map an interface as a source, and map it's functions and properties. In runtime, even if the concrete implementation has members with the same name as the target, but they are not declared in the interface, they won't be mapped.

Comment: I am not able to register it as well. The reason being if you try to register an interface then internally it tries to make an object of the same to access the properties for mapping purposes.

Comment: What version are you using? I didn't write this answer until I tested it and make sure it's correct :)